# Python Tkinter after event OOPS implementation

Tags: python, oop, tkinter

I am very new to Python and even to oops, I want to convert this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781979/call-a-function-after-program-has-been-idle-for-a-given-time) solution to oops, but it is not working. I am not able to figure out where should I put after, tick and reset functions to achieve the job.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-

import Tkinter
import time

class simpleapp_tk(Tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        Tkinter.Tk.__init__(self,parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.running = None
        self.initialize()

    def initialize(self):
        self.grid()

        self.entryVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        self.entry = Tkinter.Entry(self,textvariable=self.entryVariable)
        self.entry.grid(column=0,row=0,sticky='EW')
        self.entry.bind("<Return>", self.OnPressEnter)
        self.entryVariable.set(u"Enter text here.")

        button = Tkinter.Button(self,text=u"Click me !",
                                command=self.OnButtonClick)
        button.grid(column=1,row=0)

        self.labelVariable = Tkinter.StringVar()
        label = Tkinter.Label(self,textvariable=self.labelVariable,
                              anchor="w",fg="white",bg="blue")
        label.grid(column=0,row=1,columnspan=2,sticky='EW')
        self.labelVariable.set(u"Hello !")

        self.grid_columnconfigure(0,weight=1)
        self.resizable(True,False)
        self.update()
        self.geometry(self.geometry())       
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)
        self.after(1000, self.tick())
        self.eventbind()

    def OnButtonClick(self):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (You clicked the button)" )
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def OnPressEnter(self,event):
        self.labelVariable.set( self.entryVariable.get()+" (You pressed ENTER)" )
        self.entry.focus_set()
        self.entry.selection_range(0, Tkinter.END)

    def reset(self, *ignore): 
        self.running = None

    def tick(self, *ignore):
        if not self.running:
            self.running = time.time()
        elif time.time() - self.running > 5:
            print 'I waited 5 seconds...'
            self.running = None
        self.after(1000,self.tick())

    def eventbind(self):
        self.bind('<KEY>',self.reset())
        self.bind('<Button-1>',self.reset())



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = simpleapp_tk(None)
    app.title('my application')
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of passing your `tick`- and `rest`-functions to the `after`- and `bind`-functions, you actually call them (with `()`), so you run into a stackoverflow.

---

```
self.after(1000, self.tick())
```

should be

```
self.after(1000, self.tick)
```

both in `initialize` and in `tick`; and also

```
self.bind('<KEY>',self.reset())
self.bind('<Button-1>',self.reset())
```

should be

```
self.bind('<Key>',self.reset) # note also your type here: it's Key not KEY
self.bind('<Button-1>',self.reset)
```

Comment: yeah, Thanks I changed and it worked and is this the best possible and optimized one way to do it? I mean why shouldn't we put ".after" after __main__. Sorry I am coming from functional background so little uncomfortable with Oops

Comment: If you're code is now working and you want a feedback or suggestions on optimization, I think it would be best to visit [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com), as it is specialized on, you know, code reviews.

Comment: thanks posted it http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/31582/python-tkinter-oops-code-optimization